# Problem connection from local machine to PostgreSQL container in Mac Os

Tags: postgresql, macos, docker, phpstorm

So, after starting the PostgreSQL container, I try to connect to the database from my client(PhpStorm), but when connecting, a connection error occurs! On Linux everything works fine, but on Mac there are problems!

[image]

my port 5432
and host which I get from `docker inspect <container_name> IP`

when I ping host which docker inspect gave me it shows:

> Request timeout for icmp_seq 0

Has anyone encountered such a problem?

Comment: so there's no connection from your host to your container? What IP address did you try to ping? What IP address are you trying to connect to?

Answer (score 1):

From your image, It shown that you had map local machine port by 5433 not 5432.
just try by change port inside phpStorm from 5432 to 5433.